# How to make a fixed width center 3 column layout?

Tags: css, layout

I am trying to make a layout with three columns that fills the entire window.  The middle column should be centered in the page and have a fixed width (in pixels, not percentage).  The left and right divs should be equal in width but their width would vary with the remaining window width.

Here is the Html:

```
 <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="left">
       left content
    </div>
    <div id="middle">
       middle content
    </div>
    <div id="right">
       right content
    </div>
</div>
```

Is there a way to do this layout with just CSS (no JavaScript)?  If not is it possible to do it with tables?

Here is a couple links I have found so far with three column layouts.  None offer the constraints I need.

http://www.dynamicdrive.com/style/layouts/category/C10/ 
http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/perfect-3-column.htm

Thanks in advance for your help.

Edit:
   More specifically I would like the following to hold: (values in pixels)

```
middle.width = 500
left.width = right.width = (window.width <= 500) ? 0 : (window.width - 500) / 2;
```

Edit:
  Here is a JavaScript solution:

```
window.onresize = function() {
   var width = ((window.innerWidth - 500) / 2) + "px";
   document.getElementById("right").style.width = width; 
   document.getElementById("left").style.width = width; 
}​
```

Comment: Take a look at http://960.gs/

Answer (score 0):

you can try using a table with width=100% and three columns, set middle column static width.

```
<table width="100%">
   <tr>
     //left col
      <td>
      </td>

     //main col
     <td style="width:500px;">
     </td>

     //right col
     <td>
     </td>

  </tr>
</table>
```

try inserting in each column a block element like div or p, empty columns may behave wierd :)

Comment: Ahh, works great:
http://jsfiddle.net/wRL3j/26/

I put a space in the left and right data elements to keep them from collapsing.  
Sadly I cannot use this because there cannot be a minimum width to the middle element and there are artifacts when the screen is collapsed.

Comment: Edit: There can be a minimum width but the left td element will not completely collapse.

Comment: did you try to add a min-width to #left and #right?
like http://jsfiddle.net/wRL3j/37/